# Image upload to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

So I managed to set-up a simple test page to upload and store image to my database however I am unsure of whether the storage is successful.

Whenever I store the image into my table under the column `Image` with the datatype `Image`, this is what is in the new row `<Binary data>`. Is this `<Binary data>` the image?

I was expecting it to display the image in '0' and '1' so I can compare the different items stored. But does having "" stored means that my image had been successfully stored?

My website's logic is coded in c#.

And also I had been trying to find sources with examples to how I may retrieve my image for display.

This is my current insert statement

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into ImageTotable "
    + "(myphoto,name) values (@photo, @name)", con);
```

To retrieve the data will this work?

```
SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("Select * from ImageTotable WHERE userid ='1'", con);
```

So if I use a datareader to store the selected items, what can I store my image to so that it will display, a label, image button, etc?

And how do I store the image into the variables? For example if I want to store text I would use:

```
pw = dr["password"].ToString();**
```

Therefore for images what would it be like?

EDIT: Full button on click event to handle the image strage

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=*;Initial Catalog=*;Integrated Security=True");
    if (!FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "Please Select Image File";    //checking if file uploader has no file selected


    }
    else
    {
        int length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] pic = new byte[length];


        FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, length);

        try
        {


            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into ImageTotable "
              + "(myphoto,name) values (@photo, @name)", con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", pic);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Image Uploaded Sucessfully";  //after Sucessfully uploaded image

        }
        finally
        {
             con.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A31444+httphandler+image

Comment: I think it's better for you to store the image in the sperate folder and store the path of this image into database.

Comment: @imJustice, while that does have its benifits, it does not scale well when you have multiple instances of the database, try to back it up, or move the database. You could try using [filestream](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) as an alternative.

Comment: @imJustice, he would need source control then because keeping images synched between prod and dev is a real pain.

Comment: @gunr2171 What exactly do you mean by multiple instances of the database? Is it when many users connect to my database at the same time?

Comment: @gunr2171, IrishChieftain both of you are correct. I think it is no a simple answer about store image into db or not. It really depends on the requirement of the system. Refer to this question stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/… . There are more detail answers about store images into database or not

Comment: @Damienn, what I mean by "multiple instances" is you could have one database on a Production server and another on a Dev server. If you tried to copy one to the other you would also have to separately copy your image repository.

Comment: another way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlxsGdIJ6x8

Answer (score 0):

First, the `Image` type in Db maps to `Byte[]` in C#, so you should convert your image into `Byte[]` before inserting into your database. For retrieving your image from the database, you can use the code:

```
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Byte[]);// you can read the image by dataadapter or datareader
 System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Here is a good link: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/how-to-insert-images-into-database-and.html and hope it can help you.

Comment: I believe I had already converted my image to bytes before storage.

Answer (score 0):

here is a complete tutorials.

http://freakzmenia.blogspot.com/2010/11/image-saveretrieve-c-web-sql-server.html

http://freakzmenia.blogspot.com/2010/10/image-saveretrieve-c-windows-form-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

This always helps me. 'fileupload' is the File Upload Control Name.

```
protected void Upload_btn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (fileupload.HasFile)
   {
     if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName == "")
      {}
     else
      {
       try
        {
          int filesize = fileupload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
          if (filesize > 819200)
           {Label1.Text = "File Size Should be Less than 800Kb";
            }
           else
           {string serverFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
            byte[] documentBinary = new byte[filesize];
            fileupload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(documentBinary, 0, filesize);

            string mainquery = "";
            mainquery = "insert into table(DocName,DocSize,Data,ContentType)       values(@DocName,@DocSize,@Data,@ContentType)";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand files_insert_cmd = new SqlCommand(mainquery,con);
            files_insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocName", serverFileName);
            files_insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocSize",fileupload.PostedFile.ContentLength);
            files_insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", documentBinary);
         files_insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType",fileupload.PostedFile.ContentType);
            files_insert_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
         }
     }
  catch (Exception e1)
      {
         Label1.Text = e1.ToString();
         Label1.Visible = true;
      }

   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in advance, because i am about to ask a stupid question. How are you checking data in table? are you right clicking on table and selecting edit top 200 rows
If you do like this, it will always show you as < binary Data > where as if you run sql query you can see actual characters in varbinary(max) column or Image column